# iPhone API get local device phone number

Tags: ios, iphone

Does anyone know how I can get the phone number of the device I am developing on so that I may use it in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find how to get the iphone sim number as string

http://blog.timeister.com/2009/06/25/objective-c-get-iphone-number/

code:

NSString *num = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@”SBFormattedPhoneNumber”];
NSLog(@”Phone Number: %@”, num);

Adrian